# How do you run a funciton when a React-Table (v6) Tree Table segment opens?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm using [React Table (version 6)](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6).

My table is using the [Tree Table HoC](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#treetable)

[image: tree-table hoc example]

I need to run some code when one of the tree table segments open. I can't figure out how to do that though.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The key ended up being the `onExpandedChange` prop.

```js
const toArray = iterable => [].slice.call(iterable)

const Table = () => {
    const $tableWrapper = useRef()

    const getGroupFromIndexPath = indexPath => {
        return indexPath.reduce(($parentElem, index) => {
            return toArray($parentElem.children).filter($child => $child.classList.contains('rt-tr-group'))[index]
        }, $tableWrapper.current.querySelector('.rt-tbody'))
    }

    return (
        <div ref={$tableWrapper}>
            <ReactTable
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                pivotBy={['name']}
                // I have no idea what the 1st parameter value is supposed to represent:/
                onExpandedChange={(value1, indexPath, event, rowData) => {
                    const $parentGroup = getGroupFromIndexPath(indexPath)
                    const $childGroup = $parentGroup.querySelector('.rt-tr-group')

                    if ($childGroup) {
                        // The expander is open
                    } else {
                        // The expander is closed
                    }
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I've left a lot of code off in this example to give focus to how I implemented `onExpandedChange`.